# How can I make the image smaller width? Masonry

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry

Basically not know how to change the width of the image so it looks like in design.

I'm new to working with this library and I want to know how I can change my example to be like in design.

The middle image is smaller than the other two.
Also to be preserved and height as all three

I  have this [sample](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEVoJo)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
  <div class="grid-item item-1">
    <img src="http://bagelhousecafe.ch/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/img-01.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item item-2">
    <img src="http://bagelhousecafe.ch/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/img-02.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="grid-item item-3">
    <img src="http://bagelhousecafe.ch/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/img-03.png" />
  </div>

</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

/* force scrollbar */
html { overflow-y: scroll; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */
.item-1,.item-3{
  width:40%;
}
.grid {
  background: #DDD;
}

/* clear fix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- .grid-item ---- */

.grid-sizer,
.grid-item {
  width: 33.333%;
}

.grid-item {
  float: left;
}

.grid-item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**CODE JS:**

```
// external js: masonry.pkgd.js, imagesloaded.pkgd.js

// init Masonry after all images have loaded
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
  $grid.masonry({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    percentPosition: true,
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
  }); 
});
```

[And here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlhCd.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need to use Masonry for this? The heights are the same.

Comment: Height is not the same and yes I need this library

Answer (score 0):

Minor change in these css declaration will fix the issue

```
.grid-item {
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 200px; // Added height
}

.grid-item {} // No need of float left

.grid-item img {
  min-width: 100%; //defined max-height,max-width & min-height
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/vasi_32/pen/JKGzJB)

Comment: It is perfect but the middle column can be less?